How can I prove the existence of multiplicative inverses for the complex number system
If the complex number system is defined to be the set $\mathbb C = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ (called the complex numbers) together with the two functions from $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C $ into $\mathbb C$, denoted by $+$ and $\times$ (multiplication), that are given by $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c, b+d)$ and $(a,b)\times(c,d) = (ac-bd, ad+bc)$ for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$.
If I am trying to prove the existence of the multiplicative inverses for $\mathbb C$, do I need to begin by laying out that $$(ac-bd, ad+bc)^{-1} \times (ac-bd, ad+bc) = 1? $$

You pick an arbitrary nonzero element, $(a, b)$, and find another element that multiplies with it to make $1$, and prove that this does indeed work for the operation you've defined. You know which element to pick if you know how to divide complex numbers.

So does this mean I pick some arbitrary nonzero element (a,b) in the sense that I literally pick a number or I am just stating that I am picking some arbitrary nonzero element? Also, I assume this means I have to multiply this element I pick with the conjugate? That's what I can think of in terms of dividing complex numbers.

Please use MathJax to typeset mathematical formulas in your MSE posts. As for the mathematics, you need to show that if $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$, then there are $c$ and $d$ such that $ac - bd = 1$ and $bc + ad = 0$. (If you are new to the complex numbers, then this is a hard exercise unless you have been shown something similar in class.)

I understand multiplying by the conjugate, but I think I am struggling with how to actually write the proof itself. I am confused when it comes to beginning this proof. Do I define legitimate complex numbers and multiply them to prove?

Cf. this question

There's no multiplicative inverse for zero

You want to prove a statement of the form: "For any $X$ there exists a $Y$ such that $P(X,Y)$ holds."
A typical proof for such a statement starts as follows: "Let $X$ be arbitrary. Then define $Y$ to be ...". Then you only have to show that $P(X,Y)$ does indeed hold for the $Y$ you defined.
Hence, in your case you start: "Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$  be an arbitrary complex number such that at least one of $a$ and $b$ is not zero. Then, we define the complex number $(c,d) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ by setting $c := \dots$ and $d := \dots$."
Then, you conclude the proof by showing that you have $(a,b)*(c,d)=(1,0)$.

I understand the method of proving this now, so thank you for that. How can I show $$(a,b) * (c,d) = (1,0)$$ if everything is arbitrary? Would I not have to legitimately show using $$a+bi$$ and $$\frac{1}{a+bi}$$ that multiplying these two in the form of $$(a,b)$$ would equal (1,0)?

$c$ is not arbitrary; $\quad c:=\dfrac a{a^2+b^2}$

Oh, so I basically follow suit from your comments earlier using this proof framework. That makes a lot more sense now.

What you are allowed to do depends on your definitions (and what you have already proven about them). Taking only the definitions you provided in your question as given, complex numbers must always be of the form $(a,b)$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Other things like $a+bi$ or $\frac{1}{a+bi}$ are not legitimate complex numbers at that point (the latter, in particular, is just shorthand for the multiplicative inverse you haven't proven yet that it even exists).
And, as J. W. Tanner mentions: $c$ and $d$ are not arbitrary in this proof, but defined explicitly (depending on $a$ and $b$).

(though, for the purpose of learning, I would highly recommend trying to find the right definition for $c$ and $d$ yourself instead of just copying them from someone else)

I understand. Does this mean I do not need to mathematically show $$(a,b)*(c,d)$$ I am only arbitrarily defining (a,b) then explicity defining (c,d) properly and setting up the proof to assert that this equals (1,0)?

OH! I just got it. I wrote it all out defining c and d explicitly. This makes so much sense. Thank you to everyone.

You are arbitrarily choosing $(a,b)$ to be arbitrary (so long as $(a,b)\ne (0,0)$).  Then you are solving for $(c,d)$ which are NOT arbitrary but uniquely defined for $a$ and $b$.  You can do this two ways.  You can say $(a,b)(c,d)=1$ requires that $ac-bd=1$ and $bc+ad=0$ and that requires that $c=..whatever..$ and $d=..something..$.  OR you can just out and out say: Let $(a,b)$ be an arbitrary number and let $(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2} ,-\frac b{a^2+b^2})$ be another and then show that $(a,b)(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2},-\frac b{a^2+b^2})=1$.

Please allow me to adopt the standard convention of writing $a + bi$ rather than $(a, b)$ for the complex number represented by the pair of real numbers $(a, b)$ - this makes it much easier to think algebraically and you can easily convert back into the notation with pairs if you so wish.
There is a really usefully operation on the complex numbers called conjugation that maps $z = a + bi$ to $\overline{z} = a - bi$.It's easy to check that
$$z\overline{z} = (a + bi) \overline{(a + bi)} = (a + bi)(a - bi) = a^2 + b^2$$
So now we're in business: $z\overline{z} = a^2 + b^2$ is a non-negative real number that is positive if $z \neq 0 + 0i$. So if we put:
$$z^{-1} = \frac{\overline{z}}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} - i\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$$
we have that $zz^{-1} = 1$, i.e., that $z^{-1}$ as defined above is the multiplicative inverse of $z$.

Easiest is to argue that $$re^{i\theta} \times \left[ ~\frac{1}{r} e^{-i\theta} ~\right] = 1.$$
Here, $~e^{i\theta}~$ is syntactic sugar for $~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).$
Further, any non-zero complex number $~z = x + iy~$ can be expressed as
$~re^{i\theta},~$ where $~r \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ and $~-\pi < \theta \leq \pi,~$ via the following conversion procedure:

$\displaystyle r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.~$

$\displaystyle \theta~$ is the unique element in $~(-\pi,\pi],~$ 
such that $~\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r}, ~\sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{r}.$



It's bizarre to introduce transcendental functions for the trivial algebra involved here.

@RobArthan The algebra is not so trivial, to the original poster.  Further, using the $~e^{i\theta}~$ function has the existence of inverses as a direct consequence.  So, one might reasonably argue that avoiding the transcendental functions constitutes trying to re-invent the wheel, which is generally not a good idea.

This method of proving makes a lot of sense to me, I am just trying to get a grasp as to how the others are providing ways of proving this. Oddly enough, I understand this method more than the others.

Introducing the transcendental functions here is a very bad idea. The elementary algebra involved in understanding complex conjugation is very instructive: the geometry of the complex plane and of linear transformations on it is much easier to understand than the the geometry of the universal cover of  the punctured plane.

@RobArthan We're going to have to agree to disagree.  The transcendental function $~re^{i\theta}~$ is nothing more than a visualization that $~(x + iy)~$ represents some unique complex number on the circle of radius $~r.~$  The corresponding intuition is so basic, that the comment left by user1217275, following this answer, is not surprising.

That geometric intuition is very helpful in many circumstances, but it breaks down in so many contexts where the algebra stands up. But as you say, let's agree to disagree on this MSE question.


If I am trying to prove the existence of the multiplicative inverses for $\mathbb C$, do I need to begin by laying out that $(ac-bd, ad+bc)^{-1} \times (ac-bd, ad+bc) = 1? $

No; given $(a,b)\ne(0,0)$, you want to prove there exists $(c,d)$ such that $(a,b)\times(c,d)=(1,0)$.
It is given that $(a,b)\times(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$, so you want $\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}\pmatrix{c\\d}=\pmatrix{1\\0}$.
If you know how to invert a $2\times2$ matrix, set $\pmatrix{c\\d}=\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}^{-1}\pmatrix{1\\0},$
and you are essentially done.
